# My footer background image is not showing

Tags: html, css

My css code

`.footer-container{
 background: url(../images/footer.jpg);}`

html code

`<div id="footer-container">`

Answer (score 3):

To target an id you have to use the hash:

```
 #footer-container{ background: url(../images/footer.jpg);}
```

Or change the id into a class attribute:

```
 <div class="footer-container">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css has a class of footer-container and the HTML has an ID of footer-container so you may want to check that. It should be:

```
#footer-container{ background: url(../images/footer.jpg);}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ids** use the `#`

*example*
`#footer-container {...}`

**classes** use the `.`

*example*
`.footer-container {...}`